# Force PyInstaller to include all built-in modules

Tags: python, pyinstaller, glob, analysis, built-in

We are building an application that dynamically imports other Python and runs it.  We don't know ahead of time what modules those other Python files might need, but these other Python files should be able to rely on having all built-in modules available.

Because of how PyInstaller's analysis works, we are losing a lot of built-in modules if our main application isn't using them.

**Is there a way to force PyInstaller to include everything in Lib (not site-packages)?**

*Note: we have considered building up a list of hidden imports, but:*

1. *this would need to be done programmatically so that we don't need to manually rebuild this if we change Python versions (and thus change the built-in modules list)*
2. *this just "feels" like working around the Analysis step instead of removing it, and I'm a little worried about what side effects that might have.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is third-party module `stdlib_list` that has all the modules in the Lib. It also includes built-in modules. Use it from the PyInstaller's [hook](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html) for main/any module of your app:

```py
import stdlib_list
hiddenimports = list(stdlib_list.stdlib_list())
```

My research shows that there is no built-in way to list standard modules from polluted environment. I suppose that's the reason for PyInstaller no having an easy option to include Standard Lib.

Comment: Fair enough.  Unfortunately with this being a 3rd party module it doesn't totally address #1 in the hidden import concerns above, but it may still be helpful.

You mentioned "no built-in way to list standard modules from a polluted environment."  Is there a built-in way to list all modules (including site-packages)?  This would truly be like skipping the Analysis step.  I see this can be done with pip but we wouldn't want pip to be available in this app.

Comment: @gkimsey there are `pkgutil.iter_modules` and `sys.builtin_module_names`. Note that polluted site-packages make build process non-reproducible and may include something that may break your build. Doing builds within clean virtualenv is advisable.